Hierarchical Dirichlet Gibbs Sampling for Unobserved Data
I am interested in estimating the distribution of an unobserved variable $U$ that takes values discrete values in {0,1} using the observed data $X_i$ which are also discrete random variables, in this case taking values in {0,1,2}. The distribution of X depends on the associated U. To estimate the distribution of U, I want to perform Gibbs sampling but unfortunately the computational results do not match my expected theory. I am unsure on which I am making a mistake. The model is the following:
\begin{align*}
&P_u\sim Dir(\underline{\alpha})\\
&U|P_u\sim P_u\\
&P_x\sim \delta_{U=0}Dir(\underline{\beta}_0)+\delta_{U=1}Dir(\underline{\beta}_1)\\
&X|U,P_x\sim P_x\\
&\text{with }\underline{\alpha}=(\alpha^0,\alpha^1)\quad \underline{\beta_i} = (\beta_i^0,\beta_i^1,\beta_i^2)
\end{align*}
Since U is discrete, $P_u$ can also be seen as a $Beta(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ distribution. I believe (not sure) that previous model can be represented with thefollowing graphical model:

I am (possibly) confused by my own notation and am unsure if there needs to be an arrow from U to $P_x$ (I do not believe so as it is written independently of U).
Since I am interested in a Gibbs procedure for U my approach is the following:

Randomly initialize all the $U_i$
Update the posterior distribution of $P_u$ as $$P_u|X_1,\dots X_n, U_1,\dots,U_n,P_x\propto \prod U_i|P_U\cdot P_u\sim Dir(\alpha^0+\sum \delta_{U_i=0},\alpha^1+\sum \delta_{U_i=1})$$
Sample $P_u$ from the updated distribution $P_u|X_1,\dots X_n, U_1,\dots,U_n,P_x$.
Update the posterior distribution of $U_i$ as $$U_i|X_i,P_x,P_u\propto X_i|P_x,U_i\cdot U_i|P_u$$
Now sample new $U_i$s from $U_i|X_i,P_x,P_u$
Update the posterior distribution of $P_x$ as $$P_x|X_1,\dots X_n, U_1,\dots,U_n,P_u\propto \prod X_i|P_x,U_i\cdot P_x\sim Dir(\beta^0_{U_i}+\sum \delta_{X_i=0}\delta_{U=U_i},\dots,)$$
Sample a new $P_x$ from $P_x|X_1,\dots X_n, U_1,\dots,U_n,P_u$
Repeat from step 1

I think that this is a correct implementation of Gibbs sampling for such model and taking the sample average of the observed samples $P_u^i$ from the posterior Dirichlet, should give me consistent estimates for the true $P_u$. I have also tried simulating this with the following python code:
def gibbs(data, alpha_0U, alpha_0X, iter):
au = 2
ax = 3

# Im not supposed to know U so I sample randomly.
data['U'] = np.random.choice([0,1],size= len(data['U']),p =[0.5,0.5])

alpha_X = alpha_0X

alpha_U = alpha_0U

PthetaX_U = [dirichlet.rvs(alpha_X[i])[0] for i in range(au)]

PU_thetaU = dirichlet.rvs(alpha_U)[0]
Post_U = np.zeros((au, ax))

ret_PU_thetaU = np.zeros((iter,au))
ret_PX = np.zeros((iter,au,ax))

counts = np.zeros((au, ax), dtype=int)

for g in range(iter):
    print('Iter',g)
    for ix in range(ax):
        for iu in range(au):
            Post_U[iu, ix] = PU_thetaU[iu] *  PthetaX_U[iu][ix]
        Post_U[:, ix] = Post_U[:, ix] / np.sum(Post_U[:, ix])

    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=10)

    data['U'] = data.apply(lambda row: np.random.choice(range(au), size=1, p=Post_U[:, row['X']])[0], axis=1)
    unique_pairs, pair_counts = np.unique(list(zip(data['U'], data['X'])), axis=0, return_counts=True)
    counts[tuple(zip(*unique_pairs))] = pair_counts

    alpha_X = alpha_0X + counts

    PthetaX_U = [dirichlet.rvs(alpha_X[i])[0] for i in range(au)]
    ret_PX[g,:,: ] = PthetaX_U

    alpha_U = alpha_0U + np.bincount(data['U'], minlength=au)
    PU_thetaU = dirichlet.rvs(alpha_U)[0]

    ret_PU_thetaU[g,:] = PU_thetaU
    print('------')

return ret_PU_thetaU, ret_PX

Unfortunately the results are not what I expect, even when running for a long time and removing a "burn-in sample". Consider the following data generating process:
def gen_data(n):
U,X = [],[]
for _ in range(n):
    uu = np.random.choice(range(2), size=1, p=[0.8,0.2])[0]
    U.append(uu)

    if uu == 0:
        xx = np.random.choice(range(3), size=1, p=[0.05, 0.35,0.6])[0]
    elif uu ==1:
        xx = np.random.choice(range(3), size=1, p=[0.6, 0.15,0.25])[0]

    X.append(xx)

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'U': U})
return df

The observed result from a trial run is the following:

I am now wondering if I have made a mistake with the theory, my (conditional) independependencies do not hold or rather my implementation is incorrect. Any help, or advice would be greatly appreciated.
